# IPC and/or shared memory in Linux for a beginner

Tags: ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to write a small C project just to understand some basic mechanism in IPC and shared memory. What I would like to do is to have a process that increments a counter and one or more processes that look at this shared variable and perform actions. It would be nice if the codes of these processes are stored in functions. Something like

```
int counter = 0 ;

int timer ( ) { counter ++ } ;

int proc1 ( ) { /* action 1 */ } ;

int terminator ( ) { if ( counter >= 10 ) /* terminate processes */} ;

int main ( ) {
  counter = 0 ;
  /* launch timer, proc1, and terminator */
  return 0 ;
}
```

Can someone provide me an example on how to do this? Maybe IPC and shared memory is not the right technique, I am a newbie in this argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After few days I could find a solution but using Posix threads instead

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 10

int counter = 0 ;
pthread_mutex_t counter_mutex ;
pthread_cond_t counter_condition ;

void * increment ( void * arg ) {
    int i = 0 ;
    sleep ( 1 ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < N ; i ++ ) {
        pthread_mutex_lock ( & counter_mutex ) ;
        counter ++ ;
        pthread_cond_signal ( & counter_condition ) ;
        pthread_mutex_unlock ( & counter_mutex ) ;
        sleep ( 1 ) ;
    }
    pthread_exit ( ( void * ) 0 ) ;
} ;

void * watch ( void * arg ) {
    pthread_mutex_lock ( & counter_mutex ) ;
    while ( counter < N ) {
        pthread_cond_wait ( & counter_condition , & counter_mutex ) ;
        printf ( "counter = %d\n" , counter ) ;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock ( & counter_mutex ) ;
    pthread_exit ( ( void * ) 0 ) ;
} ;

int main ( ) {

    int i ;
    pthread_t threads [ 2 ] ;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_mutex_init ( & counter_mutex , ( void * ) 0 ) ;
    pthread_cond_init ( & counter_condition , ( void * ) 0 ) ;

    pthread_attr_init ( & attr ) ;
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate ( & attr , PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE ) ;

    pthread_create ( & threads [ 0 ] , & attr , increment , ( void * ) 0 );
    pthread_create ( & threads [ 1 ] , & attr , watch , ( void * ) 0 ) ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++ ) {
        pthread_join ( threads [ i ] , ( void * ) 0 ) ;
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy ( & attr ) ;
    pthread_mutex_destroy ( & counter_mutex ) ;
    pthread_cond_destroy ( & counter_condition ) ;

    return 0 ;
} ;
```

Any dis/advantages in using this method than IPC?